# Удаление елемента родителя. Вызов в контроллере по ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

В контроллере после определенного действия нужно удалить родительский блок элемента.

Почему то банальные попытки на подобии

```
parent().remove()
```

не работают.

код где пытаюсь удалить

```
PortalApi.delFavorServices(data)
                     .then(function () {
                         $scope.notifySuccessMssg(mssgDel);
                     }, function(reason) {
                         $scope.notifyErrorMssg(mssgDel);
                     });
                 if(categoryId == "favorites"){
                     console.log('removed');
                     this.parent().remove();
                 }
```

console.log выбивает когда нужно. но удаления не происходит.

еще и ошибку выбивает

```
TypeError: this.parent.remove is not a function
```

Comment: в then вставлял. тоже не помогло

Comment: В приведенном фрагменте кода, удаление выполняется сразу после вызова PortalApi.delFavorServices. Чему в этот момент равен this, непонятно, потому что нет контекста. Вероятно, не тому что вы ожидаете.

Comment: все. вопрос уже решил. инит вызываю. выполняется проверка на свойство. и так как там фолс. то обьект не отображает.